# Trying to send a friend request

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to send a friend request with my code. I followed an easy tutorial on youtube. The code does not have any errors but its not working. Here the important part:[image: The task is not sucessfull]

```
fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    userId = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_id");
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId);
    FriendRequest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friend_req");
    currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();


    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (currentstate.equals("not_friends")){

                FriendRequest.child(currentuser.getUid()).child(userId).child("request_type").setValue("sent")
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            FriendRequest.child(userId).child(currentuser.getUid()).child("request_type").setValue("received").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Toast.makeText(otherProfile.this, "SEND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(otherProfile.this, "FAiLED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Maybe the problem is that I am not using a RealTimeDatabase ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your screenshot is showing Firestore, but your code is working with Realtime Database.  These are completely different database products.  Your code needs to match the product you're using.  Be sure the check the product documentation for examples of correct usage.